# Why are there differences in USB flash drive throughput between different computers?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a USB(2.0) Flash Drive. I was recently moving data off my desktop to my laptop.

I noticed that off my desktop I only get about 4-6MB/s. (It fluctuates quite a bit)

But on my laptop I get a solid 20MB/s.

What could be the issue with my desktop? Is it a driver issue or something?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe your desktop has more things on the same bus that are taking IO.

Comment: Did you plug it into a USB 2.0 port? Some old desktop cases had only USB 1.0 available in the front.

Comment: Your desktop could also be indexing the drive or running Windows update.

Comment: @WindowsEscapist I have indexing off, and I only have one other device plugged into that bus and It is off right now. And Karan It is plugged into a 2.0 port. Thanks for the answers/comments

Comment: Writing requires erasing, and erasing is slow. Reading doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are writing from the desktop to the flash drive, and reading from the flash drive to the laptop, these seem like reasonable numbers.  I have more than one flash drive that reads between 18-22MBps and writes at no more than 5MBps.

Also depends on whether you're seeing it when it's copying one large file, or many small files.  Usually copying many small files is substantially slower.

Comment: write speed are (almost) always much slower than read speed. so it's easy to understand that writing from the desktop to the USB flash drive is slower than copy from flash to laptop